# PHP Laravel v5.7.0 Getting 404 Page Not Found for Equipment Resource Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting an error 404 Page Not Found while displaying the index.blade.php view for the Equipment Resource Controller.

Here are my files:

App\Http\Controllers\EquipmentController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EquipmentController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
   {
        return View::make('equipments.index'); 
   }

   ...
}
```

routes\web.php

```
Route::resource('equipment', 'EquipmentController');
```

resources\views\equipments\index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Equipment</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Chillers</th>
                <th>Setpoint</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                     <td>Chiller 1</td>
                     <td>32&#176C;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>Chiller 2</td>
                     <td>32&#176C;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>Chiller 3</td>
                     <td>32&#176C;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </body>
 </html>
```

I have already tried doing 'php artisan cache:clear' to no effect. Please kindly tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I have been doing wrong. With the configuration above, I have been trying to access the URL '127.0.0.1:8000/equipments' instead of '127.0.0.1:8000/equipment' as indicated by the route in 'php artisan route:list'.